# ComboBox binding to grouped collection

Tags: c#, binding, uwp, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

I'm facing a very difficult problem with binding. The app attached is extremely simple as you can see and is a trimmed down reproduction of the original code in which the bug appears.
To reproduce the problem, launch the app and press the 3 buttons with the **+** icon starting from left to right. These buttons will add 3 items in the collection. Then press the 4th button to navigate to the second page. On the second page select the **TEA** element from the combobox. Go back to the main page and press the last button on the right which adds the **CAPPUCCINO** product to the list. You will get an `Value does not fall within expected range` exception. I would like to know why this happens and not just a workaround which could not be the real solution to the problem. As you can see the problem appears under very specific circumstances.
Notes:

- removing the static variable and passing the collection instance in the `Navigate` call to the second page does not fix the problem
- in place of the `Add` call there was an insertion in order which called `Insert` on the collection. I removed it and the `Insert` is not the problem nor the solution
- removing the `CollectionViewSource` on the second page does not fix the problem
- <s>creating another specular collection `GroupByLetter2` for the combobox does not fix the problem (see **test1** branch)</s>

**UPDATE**: at the end I was able to set the `CollectionViewSource.Source = null` on the `UserControl.Unloaded` event and that fixed it. But the question is still open on the working theory.

https://github.com/albertorivelli/app1

This is the main page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvsProductsLetter" IsSourceGrouped="true" />
</Page.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="gwProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsProductsLetter}}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The `CollectionViewSource` it's populated in code-behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public static ProductCollection _productcollection;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;

        _productcollection = new App1.ProductCollection();

        cvsProductsLetter.Source = _productcollection.GroupByLetter;
    }
```

This is the `ProductCollection` class:

```
public class ProductCollection
{
    public ObservableCollection<ProductGroup> _groupsletter;

    public ObservableCollection<ProductGroup> GroupByLetter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_groupsletter == null)
            {
                _groupsletter = new ObservableCollection<ProductGroup>();
            }

            return _groupsletter;
        }
    }

    public void Add(Product newitem)
    {
        AddToLetterGroup(newitem);
    }

    private void AddToLetterGroup(Product item)
    {
        int i;
        ProductGroup prodgr = null;

        // get group from letter
        for(i = 0; i < _groupsletter.Count; i++)
        {
            if (String.Equals(_groupsletter[i].Key, item.Name[0].ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                prodgr = _groupsletter[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        //new letter
        if (prodgr == null)
        {
            prodgr = new ProductGroup();
            prodgr.Key = item.Name[0].ToString();
            prodgr.Add(item);
            _groupsletter.Add(prodgr);
        }
        else
        {
            prodgr.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

public class ProductGroup : ObservableCollection<Product>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

..and the `Product` class

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = "";

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (!String.Equals(_name, value))
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

This is the second page with the combobox:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvsProductsLetter" IsSourceGrouped="true" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsProductsLetter}}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" />
</Grid>

public sealed partial class SecondPage : Page
{
    public SecondPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        cvsProductsLetter.Source = App1.MainPage._productcollection.GroupByLetter;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but please post your code here. We are (I am) not willing to download and extract a zipfile and walk through your app to help solve your problem. Narrow it down and post the relevant lines.

Comment: moved on github...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go back to the main page and press the last button on the right which adds the CAPPUCCINO product to the list. You will get an Value does not fall within expected range exception.

I can reproduce this problem in your demo. I did some test and found that on the second Page when you select **TEA**, then go back to the `MainPage` only the **T** group can be added without exception. And when you select **CAPPUCCINO** and repeat the steps, **C** group won't get exception, others will.

I guess it is due to you are sharing the same data model object between pages. For detailed root cause, I need to consult internally.

Currently the simpliest workaround is to empty the `cvsProductsLetter` in the `OnNavigatingFrom` of Second Page:

SecondPage.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    cvsProductsLetter.Source = null;
}
```

But the recommended way to solve this problem is to create a separated new data model for the second Page:

ProductCollection.cs:

```
public class ProductCollection
{
  ...
    public void CreateNewGroupByLetter(ObservableCollection<ProductGroup> oldGroupByLetter)
    {
        if (oldGroupByLetter != null&&this.GroupByLetter!=null)//add this.GroupByLetter!=null to call the setter of GroupByLetter.
        {
            foreach (var group in oldGroupByLetter)
            {
                foreach (var product in group)
                {
                    Add(new Product {
                         Name=product.Name
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void btnProdNavigate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ProductCollection newColl = new ProductCollection();
    newColl.CreateNewGroupByLetter(_productcollection.GroupByLetter);
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), newColl);
}
```

**Update:**

Here is the link to the modified demo: [App1](https://github.com/elvisxia/app1-master).

Comment: thanks for your answer, give me some time to test it on the original code. About the workaround of setting the cvs to null, It doesn't make sense to me because the second page should be destroyed (I even tried to do this explicitly). But maybe it is not gc'ed. My hypothesis is that selecting an item from the ComboBox breaks something inside the collection and that's irreversible, so it's not possible to make it with one Collection.

Comment: By creating a new data model, not only mean creating a new collection, but also mean creating a new collection with new objects inside. I checked your new demo in test 1 branch. You added the same product to two different collection, which leads to the fact that two collections share the same children inside.(in C# the object variable are reference type, by passing an object variable, you are passing a reference).

Comment: And that's why I use `Add(new Product { Name=product.Name });` to create the new collection in my answer.

Comment: yes, sorry you're right I didn't think about it. Even if it's very inefficient I could live with it. Unfortunately this does not still fix the problem, I even copied the strings. I updated the **test1** branch with these changes. But I think now the problem is narrowing down. About the workaround of setting the cvs source to null, this is not very feasible because in the original code the combobox is inside a usercontrol that is inside a datatemplate so I should put it in the destructor of the usercontrol.

Comment: I made a quick test myself and changed the `ComboBox` to a `ListView`, selected the **TEA** element and it works. I think the combobox has some problems binding a `CollectionViewSource` and/or grouped collections...

Comment: I checked your new demo, still, you are referencing to the `App1.MainPage._productcollection` object on the second page. I uploaded my demo in the answer, could you please try that. I don't have access to the source codes of `ComboBox` or `Binding`. So I can only guess that it's related to the Binding of the current selected Item in ComboBox. I have questioned it internally, let's wait for the response.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work I updated the master branch with the new changes. Let's wait for the response, maybe we can find a better way to make it work. Many thanks.